# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] update error

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error while trying to update information in mysql server:

> 'Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064
>  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near '* FROM ogrenci WHERE ID=' at line 1 in
> D:\Php\xampp\htdocs\workworkwork\index.php:78
> Stack trace:
>  #0
> D:\Php\xampp\htdocs\workworkwork\index.php(78):
> PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 {main} thrown in
> D:\Php\xampp\htdocs\workworkwork\index.php on line 78'

How can i solve this?

```
        $id=$_REQUEST['ID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ogrenci WHERE ID=$id";
        $sonuc= $db->prepare($sql);
        $sonuc->execute();
        $rs=$sonuc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You can solve it by using properly prepared statements and thereby avoiding [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: There's no point using prepared statements if you don't also use **parameters** with them. Look again at examples of the use of pdo prepared statements to see. It might also fix your issue (unless the problem is simply that $id is empty)